# Input Values in Integer Arrays in JAVA

Tags: java, arrays

So here's the deal I was messing around with **Java** trying to make a programme that would take a given `int[]` and make another `int[]` which would be in ascending order...
so here the code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Accending_order {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int[] dArray = {
            1, 34, 25, 67, 35, 68, 88
        };
        int[] oArray = new int[200];
        int[] countOf = new int[200];

        for (int i = 0; i < dArray.length; i++) {
            int NumForLoop = dArray[i];
            for (int j = 0; j < dArray.length; j++) {
                int diff = 0;
                if (j != i) diff = NumForLoop - dArray[j];
                if (diff < 0) countOf[i]++;
            }
            for (int k = 0; k < dArray.length; k++) {
                oArray[k] = dArray[dArray.length - countOf[k]];
            }
            for (int i2 = 0; i2 < oArray.length; i2++) {
                System.out.print(oArray[i2]);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

and this the ERROR it's showing :

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7
at Accending_order.main(Accending_order.java:19)
```

so help.....

Comment: which line is line 19?

Comment: What will `dArray[dArray.length - countOf[k]]` do if the count is 0? (hint, arrays are 0-indexed in Java).

Comment: this `dArray.length - countOf[k]` is giving 7

Answer (score 3):

the problem is here

```
 oArray[k] = dArray[dArray.length - countOf[k]];
```

when `countOf[k] = 0`, you are trying to access `dArray[dArray.length]` and `dArray.length` is 7, but your array contains elements at indexes 0..6